# how to set dynamic height of output panel on vf page within a section on record detail page?

Tags: visualforce, outputpanel, scrolling

i have a vf page on that i have one picklist when user select 'All' then all related record shown in pageblock table and when user select any specific then within that it show according to that. so when a user set 'All' then i set scrollbar with `<apex:outputPanel id="outerPnl"  layout="block" style="overflow: auto; height: 150px">` but use of this height get fix and when next record select then there is space get left.i just want height get dyamic.[image]

like this extra space get there i just want it is adjust according to data. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Embedded Visualforce pages always exist in a fixed-height container on the page layout, the height of which is configured in the page layout editor.

Without replacing the entire record page with a Visualforce page, it's not possible to dynamically size these embedded pages.